# Variations Problem

Tags: 2007, variations, fast-for-sharepoint

I have a SharePoint project, where when I get my `Variations.Current.GetCurrentVariation()` and I get null, and I have activated the Office SharePoint Server 2007 Publishing feature.

Can anyone help me out please to find the solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't find any documentation at all for that function call. Where did you come across it, out of curiosity?